# remap does not affect subscription addresses?

Tags: ros, remap, publisher

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was expecting  to affect the relatively addressed
subscriptions of a node, but it doesn't seem to.

```
<node name="publiser" pkg="hwu_meta_data" type="publisher_node.py"/>

<!-- the following subscriber does not hear the publisher because it's
in the wrong namespace -->
<node ns="subnamespace2" name="ns_subscriber" pkg="hwu_meta_data"
      type="subscriber_node.py" output="screen"/>

<!-- the remap moves BOTH the node AND its associated meta_data -->
<!-- NOTE: it seems the chatter topic subscribed to by remapped_ns_subcriber is not remapped so this does not receive delivery -->
<remap from="subnamespace3" to="/"/>
<node ns="subnamespace3" name="remapped_ns_subcriber"
      pkg="hwu_meta_data" type="subscriber_node.py" output="screen"/>
```

Is that deliberate or am I doing something wrong? (the publisher and subscriber implementations are essentially identical to the beginner tutorials)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/34647/remap-does-not-affect-subscription-addresses?/) by [Tom Larkworthy](https://answers.ros.org/users/2443/tom-larkworthy/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2012-05-23

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You are using remap on a global scope. Try:

```
<launch>
  <node name="publiser" pkg="hwu_meta_data" type="publisher_node.py" />
  <node ns="subnamespace3" name="remapped_ns_subcriber"
        pkg="hwu_meta_data" type="subscriber_node.py" output="screen">
    <remap from="your_topic" to="/your_topic" />
  </node>
</launch>
```

This requires to explicitly remap each topic you use but in my opinion that's much cleaner anyway.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-05-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4